# ASP.NET MVC5 でcsvをpostでダウンロードするには

Tags: asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

ASP.NET MVC5 でcsv出力をしようとしています。

パラメータの複数ある画面で、ボタンも複数あるためAjaxを使用してPostしています。
ファイルのダウンロードがされず、またファイル作成もできず困っています。

```
//以下、抜粋
$('#download').click(
            function () {
                var param= new Object();
                //param set
                if (parking != null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("CreateCsv", "Csv")",
                        data: JSON.stringify(param),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        datatype:'json',
                        success: function () {
                            debugger
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        failure: function (data) {
                            debugger
                            alert(data.StatusMessage);
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            debugger
                            alert(data.StatusMessage);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        );


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateCsv(Param Pram)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                // DB からデータ取得

                // CSV 内容生成

                 var fileName = string.Format("filename_{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));

                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvString);

                var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

                //var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(stream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames .Text.Plain);
                //fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = fileName;

                //return fileStreamResult;

                writer.Write(data);
                writer.Flush();
                stream.Position = 0;

                return File(stream, "text/csv", fileName);

            }
            return null ;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

最後の `return` する部分。

```
    return File(stream, "text/csv", fileName);
```

を、このようにしてみてはどうでしょう？

```
    return File(stream.ToArray(), "text/csv", fileName);
```

この辺の記事が、そんな風に `byte[]` に変換してから返しているので。

[ASP.NET MVC ファイルのダウンロード](http://haronoid.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/06/20/112035)
[How to download memorystream to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16558317/9014308)

おそらく、[FileResult Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.fileresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) で以下のように書いてあって、

```
Derived  System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult
         System.Web.Mvc.FilePathResult
         System.Web.Mvc.FileStreamResult
```

[FileStreamResult Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) でこうなので、`MemoryStream` でも行ける？ となったのかも。

> Sends binary content to the response by using a `Stream` instance.

Comment: 上記を行ってみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 自己解決ですが、Fileでのリターンを諦めStringで返してクライアント側からblobのUrlを呼ぶようにしました。文字コードがUTF-8にしかならず困っていますがこれに関しては別の問題なのでもう少し調べてみようと思います。

Comment: ヒントをいただき、ありがとうございました。